# Fit scrollable nested div to screen

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have the following HTML tree:

```html
<html>
  <body class="body">
    <header>
      <div class="ribbon">
        <span class="ribbon-title">Template</span>
      </div>
    </header>
    <div>
      <div class="border">some content</div>
      <div class="bar">other dynamic content</div>
      <div class="scrollable">
        <div>A</div>
        <div>A</div>
        <div>A</div>
        <div>A</div>
        <div>A</div>
        <div>A</div>
        <div>A</div>
        <div>A</div>
        <div>A</div>
        <div>A</div>
        <div>A</div>
        <div>A</div>
        <div>A</div>
        <div>A</div>
        <div>A</div>
        <div>A</div>
        <div>A</div>
        <div>A</div>
        <div>A</div>
        <div>A</div>
        <div>A</div>
        <div>A</div>
        <div>A</div>
        <div>A</div>
        <div>A</div>
        <div>A</div>
        <div>A</div>
        <div>A</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The header has a fixed height, the div.border and the div.bar height may vary. The height of div.scrollable should fill the rest of the screen...but I am not able to.

I created a [jsFiddler](https://jsfiddle.net/emaborsa/g38cb7ye/18/).

The tree structure cannot be modified and since I have a dynamic div.bar, I cannot use static heights for css `calc`.

Could somebody tell me how to fix it just with CSS? No Javascript, no jQuery please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No problem with [Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox) and some minor additions / modifications.

- It's important to set the full size (100%) to use the full space for flex childs.
- Use overflow hidden for parents. Otherwise a child's overflow auto might not work.
- Use flex for dynamic sizes of element. Helpful for using the remaining space.

```js
// NO JavaScript required for this solution! It's just for the demo.
// Click everywhere to change text of dynamic element `.bar`.

const barElement = document.querySelector('.bar');
const loremIpsum = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod.';

window.addEventListener('click', () => {
  barElement.innerText = loremIpsum.repeat(1 + Math.random() * 4);
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

body {
  margin: 0px;
  font-family: Arial;

  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.ribbon {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  background: #494c4f;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 46px;
  padding: 0 20px;
}

.bar {
  max-height: 150px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.border {
  padding: 0px;
}

.scrollable {
  background-color: #eee;
  overflow: auto;
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <header>
      <div class="ribbon">
        <span class="ribbon-title">Template</span>
      </div>
    </header>
    <main>
      <div class="border">some content</div>
      <div class="bar">other dynamic content (click to change)</div>
      <div class="scrollable">
        <div>A</div>
        <div>B</div>
        <div>C</div>
        <div>D</div>
        <div>E</div>
        <div>F</div>
        <div>G</div>
        <div>H</div>
        <div>I</div>
        <div>J</div>
        <div>K</div>
        <div>L</div>
        <div>M</div>
        <div>N</div>
        <div>O</div>
        <div>P</div>
        <div>Q</div>
        <div>R</div>
        <div>S</div>
        <div>T</div>
        <div>U</div>
        <div>V</div>
        <div>W</div>
        <div>X</div>
        <div>Y</div>
        <div>Z</div>
        <div>0</div>
        <div>1</div>
        <div>2</div>
        <div>3</div>
        <div>4</div>
        <div>5</div>
        <div>6</div>
        <div>7</div>
        <div>8</div>
        <div>9</div>
      </div>
    </main>
  </body>
</html>
```

Or [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bvjLqdep/) if you prefer it. (No guarantee of persistence. Contains the same code that you can see here.)

I just renamed your nameless `div` with `main` for semantic reasons. Div will also work. Just add a class for css selector.

I haven't touched your HTML code. I only removed the class `.body` from `body` (useless) and `div` to `main` for selector. And changed the list content for better recognition. Just some optimizations. Not required. You can revert it if you want, it will still work.

The changes in summary: Your main content should be `display: flex` and the scrollable list `flex: 1`. With `overflow: auto` and parent `overflow: hidden`. The html-body should be full sized in this case. Voila.

Comment: Perfect! But what is the felx: 1 of main for? W or w/o seems to make no differences.

Comment: `flex: 1` is used with flexbox to extend the element to the remaining space. It's a shorthand for `flex-basic`, `flex-grow`, `flex-shrink`. With these properties you can defined the size of an element. In this case is like "auto height". I set the parent `display: flex` and `flex-direction: column`. Means all elements are aligned vertically (column). And `flex: 1` tells the child element to extend to the available space.  Searching the web offers great tutorials about "flexbox". ... `flex: 1` in `main` extends it to the remaining space after `header`. `body` has 100% height and is flexbox.

Comment: I am working now with React Portals, and the behavior is not as expected, since now I have 2 divs in the body. I figured out that it works by changing this `flex`:`1` to `flex`:`auto`. What is the difference?

Comment: `flex: auto` is equal to `flex: 1 1 auto` and [flex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex) is a shorthand for [flex-grow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-grow), [flex-shrink](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-shrink) and [flex-basis](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-basis). In this case it sets `flex-basis: auto`. The initial main size. The `auto` sizes it based on it's width and height, but is still flexible. It depends on your setup / source code. ... You could rewrite your style layout if you have issues.